# i get "Server was unable to process request.---> Access is denied", when hosting app as a usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, soap, iis-7

I'm afraid that I can't undle some configuration in IIS 7.
I have client side app in winform connect to the server side and take credindials with windows auth and it work well.
my problem is when host this client app as a UserControl in a diffrent app that host it.
in this case, i get SoapException "SoapException: Server was unable to process request.---> Access is denied, message: one or more errors accoured".

I tried to connect from the app that host the UC and I Succeed.
*I fail to debug the server side when hosting the app as usercontrol, it seems that the server side didn't get the rquest at all.

soo, I don't know what can I do more?? wish for your help.

Comment: Need to see some code before we can come up with some solutions.

Comment: my question does not really has to be with a code example, becuse it's spread on sevreal issues. I can tell you that In my client side I question the server like this. 
client: 
var service=new MyProxy(); 
service.Cradintails= CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
var t=service.GetMyData();  
server: 
[WebMethod] 
public void  GetMyData()
{ 
string logoname= HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name; myBL.Autinticate(logoname);
}
*again it work fine my app but not when I use this dll ass a usercontrol in a diffrent app.
thank you, again.